# Calculate force of impact on running dog

Tags: forces, momentum, collision

I'm going to hold a dog protection tournament. I'd like to give the audience information about the force of the impact of the running dog when it hit(attacks) the decoy on a huge screen. I'm a software developer student so I have the neccesary skills to development the software/electronics for the project. However, i'm not a physicist and I'm getting quite confused looking on all the formulas that I find online.

My question is therefore. Is it possible to calculate the force of impact in kilograms of the dog hitting the decoy (seen as a stationary object)?

As an example how should I calculate the force if say the dog weights 40kg and is running at a speed of 30 km/t?

Comment: More on animals being impacted by solid objects: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/70573

Comment: Energy $E = \frac{1}{2} ~m~ v^2$ is a good indicator for the "violence" of the impact.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that you need here is the notion of impulse.  Consider Newton's second law:

$$\sum{\vec F} = m{\vec a}$$

In our case, the only relevant force is the contact force between our dog and the decoy.  Before we move on, let's rephrase this force a little.  Acceleration is the rate of change of velocity, and we know that momentum is given by ${\vec p} = m {\vec v}$, so we have:

$$\begin{align}
m{\vec a} &= m\frac{d{\vec v}}{dt}\\
&= \frac{d}{dt}\left(m{\vec v}\right)\\
&= \frac{d{\vec p}}{dt}
\end{align}$$

So, remembering from calculus that we can say, if $F = \frac{dp}{dt}$, then we can also say $F_{avg} = \frac{\Delta p}{\Delta t}$, we only need to know how much our dog changes velocity and how much time this takes.  Let's assume our decoy stops the dog completely.  Then, we have $v_{f} = p_{f} = 0$.  Initially, we have our dog moving at $30 {\rm kmh} = 8.3 {\rm m/s}$, so we have $p_{i} = 250 {\,\,\rm kg\cdot m/s}$, so $\Delta p = -250{\,\,\rm kg\cdot m/s}$.  Now, all you need to do is to estimate the amount of time it takes for your dog to come to a stop.  I will contend that 10 seconds is too long, and 1 millisecond is too short.  You can reason about this some more to come up with a range of estimates, but it's going to depend on the composition of your decoy and of your dog to get anything much more precise than an estimate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I believe that 30 km/t is 8.33 not 108 m/s, right?

Comment: Ach!  yes, you're right, of course.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer, dont you think collision would mean that we consider the coefficient of restitution?

Comment: @SaurabhRaje: sure.  Hence "but it's going to depend on the composition of your decoy and of your dog..."